# pandas conditional str concat (multiple selection) with a Datetime column

Tags: string, pandas, datetime, conditional-statements, concatenation

This is a follow up question: Previously Ive joined only the day-ahead with the year of my Date column to make it look like day-ahead_2019 or day-ahead_2018 depending on the year in Date column

I have two columns:

```
DELIVERY_PERIOD   
day-ahead
day-ahead
week-ahead
month-ahead
week1_2019
week2_2018
```

and,

```
Date
13/05/2019
14/05/2019
11/05/2019
10/05/2019
```

Now i have multiple entries that i would like to make it "xxxxx_year"
so i tried to make a filterlist for those i wanted and with the same code i got this "TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable"
not sure if it is the way i produce my filterlist

so this is the code that is working for a single str that i wanted

```
    gas.loc[gas['Period'] == 'Day-ahead','Period'] = gas['Period'] + '_' + gas['Date'].dt.year.astype(str)
```

if i produce a filterlist

```
    filterlist = gas[gas['Period'].isin(['week-ahead','month-ahead',"day-ahead"])]

    gas.loc[gas['Period'] == filterlist,'Period'] = gas['Period'] + '_' + gas['Date'].dt.year.astype(str)
```

giving me TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

Comment: What do you get when you print filter list? Also can you print `df.dtypes`?

Comment: if i print filterlist i get the rows with all columns when i have week/month/day ahead in the Period column. period is object and date is datetime64

Comment: I think i solved it! will post an answer

Comment: Nice one, best of luck m8!

Answer (score 2):

figured out how to do it, for anyone whos interested i used:

```
    gas.loc[gas['Period'].isin(['week-ahead','month-ahead',"day-ahead"]),'Period'] = gas['Period'] + '_' + gas['Date'].dt.year.astype(str)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use numpy where.

`gas['Period]= np.where((gas['Period'].isin(['week-ahead','month-ahead','day-ahead']), gas['Period'] + '_' + gas['Date'].dt.year.astype(str), gas['Period'])`

in this case you only overwrite the columns where the filter is applying, the old one stay the same

otherwise filter your dataframe first and then Change the column:
`gas = gas[gas['Period'].isin(['week-ahead','month-ahead',"day-ahead"])]`

`gas['Period'] = gas['Period'] + '_' + gas['Date'].dt.year.astype(str)`

Comment: yes ill need to keep other rows too, thanks i tried to run the first line and i got ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index